# Serial.read(); and state machine for AT commands

Tags: serial

I have a strange type of issue: the index of the array doesn't increment and when I print the value from the *serialdata[pointingfinger]* it just gives me an empty space.
This is a state machine (I guess) that should check what is the current char that's being written into the array and its position to avoid searching it later. When we have a finished line it changes the bigger state machine to another mode (that checks if four chars further is the command) when the processing is done it should get back getting the next line.

This is Arduino Leonardo and Serial is the USB and Serial1 is where I send and receive AT commands.

```cpp
const long interval = 1000;
static long currentMillis;

char plussignpoint = 0; //To determine where is the + in +CCLK in the char array

char serialdata[256] = ""; //Array to store the chars before parsing

int rdpos = 0;

int pointingfinger = 0;

char timeen = 0;
byte stat0 = 0;
char futstat0 = 0;
char searchcharpos = 0;

char enabled = 0;

char searchchartype = 0;

char smsvalid = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial1.write("ATE0\r");
}

void loop() {
    if (millis() - currentMillis >= interval)
    {
      Serial1.print("AT+CCLK?\r"); //ask for the time

      enabled = 1;

      currentMillis = millis();
    }

    if (enabled == 1) {
      if (stat0 == 0) {
        if (Serial1.available () > 0) {
          pointingfinger++;
          serialdata[pointingfinger] = Serial1.read();
          if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '+') {

            searchcharpos = pointingfinger;
            searchchartype = 1;
            futstat0 = 1;
          }
          else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '$') {
            if (smsvalid = 1) {
              searchcharpos = pointingfinger;
              searchchartype = 2;
              futstat0 = 2;
            }
            if (smsvalid = 0) {
              stat0 = futstat0;
              pointingfinger = 0;
            }
          }
          else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '\n') {
            stat0 = futstat0;
            pointingfinger = 0;
            enabled = 0;
          }
          else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '\r') {
            stat0 = futstat0;
            pointingfinger = 0;
            enabled = 0;
          }
          else {
            stat0 = 0;
            pointingfinger = 0;
          }
        }

        if (pointingfinger == 255) {
          pointingfinger = 0;
          enabled = 0;
        }

      }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to include what AT commands it should parse:

```cpp
Arduino: AT+CCLK?

SIM800H: +CCLK: "04/01/01,01:35:31+00"

         OK
```

Comment: What data do you get from Serial? Your problem heavily depends in that data, so please include it.

Answer (score 2):

When checking value of `smsvalid` you use assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `==`.

```
            else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '$') {
                if (smsvalid == 1) {  
                    searchcharpos = pointingfinger;
                    searchchartype = 2;
                    futstat0 = 2;
                }
                if (smsvalid == 0) {
                    stat0 = futstat0;
                    pointingfinger = 0;
                }
            }
```

And also you increment `pointingfinget` prior writing to `serialdata` buffer. This means that the first character will be written at index 1. So the first character serialdata will be zero, which means empty string.

```
      pointingfinger++;
      serialdata[pointingfinger] = Serial1.read();
```

There are many issues with your code, I pasted your code to [online gdb c++ compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/HJqeGtapf), so you can play with it and see what is going on.

Those AT state machines aren't easy to finetune on Arduino. I spent a lot of time debugging similar code and found out that the best way is to unit test all possible situations in visual studio or xcode. Arduino is just C++ and if you copy/paste some portions of your code to C++ IDE, after implementing few functions or classes it should work. For example, to make your code working in XCode, I had to implement some dummy Serial1 class and simplify the loop code:

```
class _Serial1
{
    std::string buffer{"OK\r\n"};
public:
    int available()
    {
        return (int)buffer.size();
    }

    char read()
    {
        char c = buffer[0];
        buffer.erase(0, 1);
        return c;
    }
} Serial1;

void loop() {
    if (enabled == 1) {
        if (stat0 == 0) {
            if (Serial1.available () > 0) {
                pointingfinger++;
                serialdata[pointingfinger] = Serial1.read();
                if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '+') {

                    searchcharpos = pointingfinger;
                    searchchartype = 1;
                    futstat0 = 1;
                }
                else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '$') {
                    if (smsvalid == 1) {  // ==
                        searchcharpos = pointingfinger;
                        searchchartype = 2;
                        futstat0 = 2;
                    }
                    if (smsvalid == 0) { // ==
                        stat0 = futstat0;
                        pointingfinger = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '\n') {
                    stat0 = futstat0;
                    pointingfinger = 0;
                    enabled = 0;
                }
                else if (serialdata[pointingfinger] == '\r') {
                    stat0 = futstat0;
                    pointingfinger = 0;
                    enabled = 0;
                }
                else {
                    stat0 = 0;
                    pointingfinger = 0;
                }
            }

            if (pointingfinger == 255) {
                pointingfinger = 0;
                enabled = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the compiler immediatelly pointed me at the incorrect assignments and also I was able to debug the code step by step and see what is happening inside.

In my situation I was interfacing SIMCOM900 gprs module and I made a state machine that allows me to write code like this:

```
virtual void Program()
{
    switch (Pc())
    {
        case 0: _ASSERT(strlen(mApn)>0);
                Stream() << "AT+CSTT=\"" << mApn << "\",\"\",\"\"\r\n";
                break;
        case 1: Expect("OK\r\n");
                if (Expect("+CME ERROR")) { Error("CME Error when attaching apn"); Return(false);}
                if (Timeout(25000)) Return(false);
            break;
        case 2: Stream() << "AT+CIICR\r\n"; break;
        case 3: Expect("OK\r\n");
                if (Timeout(15000)) Next(); break;
        case 4: Stream() << "AT+CIFSR\r\n"; break;
        case 5: if (ReadIpAddress()) Next();
                if (Timeout(2000)) Return(false); break; // longer?
        default: Return(true);
    }
}
```

Here is a bit older version of it:
https://gist.github.com/gabonator/88b80d9c6b16d699d6f4234ebc3a2587

Comment: wow I didn't know of such way to debug Arduino programs! Thanks! In the online compiler is cout printing chars one by one and not the whole array or I am writing them to the same index?